# Restrict grep command to print file name only once

Tags: grep

I am interested in finding a string within a specific file type.
The command below serves my purpose.

```
find  /any/path -type f -name "*.log" | xargs grep -B2  -A2 'SUMMARY' {} \;
```

It gives the following output:

```
--
/path/to/file.log-line1
/path/to/file.log-line2
/path/to/file.log:text SUMMARY text
/path/to/file.log-line1
/path/to/file.log-line2
--
```

I would like the file name not to be prepended to each line. Is it possible to have the output as below?

```
--
/path/to/file.log
line1
line2
text SUMMARY text
line1
line2
--
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running this under linux with bash, you could use a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for fn in `grep --include \*.txt -lr 'SUMMARY' /any/path`; do
        echo $fn
        grep -A2 -B2 'SUMMARY' $fn
done
```

This will find all files containing the word "SUMMARY" in a recursive manner starting from the directory "/any/path". All matched files are then printed by name and the matched portion is printed with the second `grep` line.